# how to update specific div data through ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

how to update specific div data through ajax in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at the [UpdateTargetId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.updatetargetid.aspx) property:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    // you could return a PartialView here if you need more complex HTML fragment
    return Content("<span>some content</span>", "text/html");
}
```

View:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<%= Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Update div test", 
    "SomeAction", 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }
) %>
```

Comment: can you please provide an example

Comment: @Fraz, I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be to return a partil view from your controller and place the resultant html into the div.

```
    public ActionResult jQueryTagFilter(string filterBy)
    {
      //Do stuff
      return PartialView("TagList", tags);
    }
```

Then in your html;

```
    $.post("/Admin/jQueryTagFilter", { filterBy: filter }, function(newUserListHTML) {
        $("#divTags").fadeOut(300, function() {
          $"#divTags").innerHTML = newUserListHTML;
          });

        $("#divTags").fadeIn(300);
    });
```